# PHP - How do I convert string number to number

Tags: php, regex

I have a string look like this

```
$str = "one two three four five six seven eight nine
One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine
oNE tWO tHREE fOuR fIVE sIX sEVEN eIGHT nINE
ONE TWO THREE FOuR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE";
```

With PHP language which is the pattern can convert it to this string:

```
$str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
```

Comment: So you want to convert string to number in Java, JavaScript, PHP and Perl?

Comment: why not tag this as [`assembly`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) too?

Comment: Any language because I think it just a pattern :D

Comment: @FrankThai you don't have a *pattern to convert*, you have patterns to match. You have to code logic to do this.

Comment: your question is unclear. did you intentionally leave out the number 10?

Comment: and you also mispelled the word `For` which should be `Four`. unless that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **PHP** you can do something like this:

```
$string = "one two three four five six seven eight nine
One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine
oNE tWO tHREE fOuR fIVE sIX sEVEN eIGHT nINE
ONE TWO THREE FOuR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE";

$replace = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$search = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');

echo str_ireplace($search, $replace, $string);
```

As **[Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)** pointed in his comment `str_ireplace` will do the trick for insensitive replacement.

Comment: why not just `str_ireplace` for case-insensitivity and do away with `strtolower`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's very clever... I'm not php guy but thanks for that. Updating...

Comment: You're welcome, was a thought.

Comment: *Hm....*, I'm getting back `1 2 3 for 5 6 7 8 9 ten 1 2 3 For 5 6 7 8 9 Ten 1 2 3 fOR 5 6 7 8 9 TEN 1 2 3 FOR 5 6 7 8 9 TEN` and something similar from your original version.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well, that's because OP wrote "for" lol and also for got to add "ten" :P

Comment: ah I spotted the error. It's in the OP's code `For` should be `Four` etc.

Comment: and they left out `10`, so it's unclear at this point also. but I will upvote

Comment: they  edited, seems they don't want the "ten" after all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your notice, I updated the question already:D

Comment: @FrankThai you're welcome. well, you asked for a PHP solution, this one is it.